# hdfs store data in datanode distributedly

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I contructed `HDFS` (2 DataNodes).
I stored data in datanodes of `HDFS`.

I want to store the data with a balancing using two datanodes.
But I stored only one datanode when I used a `CLI` (`hadoop fs -put`)

Has anyone got a solution how can I store data as two separate data exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking how to set the replication factor. If you have 2 data nodes a replication factor of 2 would make sure all files are stored on both nodes. You can set this in hdfs-site.xml in you Hadoop conf directory. You want to set:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>
```

You can also run the `setrep` command to change the replication factor of a particular file or directory:

```
hadoop fs -setrep -R 2 <path>
```

-R of course makes it recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If your replication factor is set right and you really just want to balance out the date use:

`hadoop balancer [-threshold <threshold>]`

There is a lot of information on the rebalancer (in PDF) at the Hadoop [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/hdfs_user_guide.html#Rebalancer) page.